# Apache forbidden error when trying to run a Perl script

Tags: html, apache, perl, cgi

I'm running an old-fashioned HTML web page with a simple Perl script on a shared server so I have no access to the main `httpd.conf` file.

Suddenly, after several years, I'm getting a *"Forbidden You don't have permission to access /file on this server"*.

The Perl script runs fine from the shell so I guess it's an Apache problem, but tech support will answer only WordPress questions.

This script has been running fine for years!

Comment: Whining about it isn't useful, and not appropriate here. And if you were to come up with a question, it would be about Apache and/or file permissions, which is the domain of Super User, not StackOverflow.

Comment: httpd logs. Check them.

Comment: @Сухой27 My question was nothing like the question you said was an exact duplicate.  That question was about a perl script that was not written correctly.  Mine has been working for years but something on the server (Apache) changed, I don't have access to the administrative areas, httpd logs,, and the admins there only respond to questions about Wordpress which seems to have taken over the world. As far as I can tell, the file permissions are not the problem.  I came here because I saw that questions of this nature had been answered in the past.  Again, my perl script is written correctly!

Comment: you might need to get a new server you have full control over, AWS has a free tier that you could at least experiment with.